# Is it completely uninteresting to draw inference from insufficient statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference, missing-data, sufficient-statistics

There may be real-world scenario when this is useful. For example, sometimes we only know the minimum of $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$, and $X_i$ are assumed to be drawn from i.i.d. $N(\mu,1)$. What can we say about $\mu$? Or some data is missing, so only $X_1,X_2$ is observed, etc.

Comment: Any inference on $\mu$ based only on minima would be stronly dependent on model assumptions (probably not verifiable) so very nonrobust.

Answer (score 2):

Most inference is done using insufficient statistics, because most models do not allow for dimension reduction sufficiency (check [the Pitman-Koopman-Darmois lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Exponential_family) that states that fixed dimension sufficient statistics only exist for exponential families) and most point estimators like the MLE are not sufficient. Inference may also rely on ancillary statistics, like [rank tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance).

In the suggested example, when observing  solely $$X_{(1)}=\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\qquad X_i\stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}{\cal N}(\mu,1)$$
the issue of sufficiency gets meaningless since there is a single observation, $X_{(1)}$, which is by essence sufficient. Looking at its distribution,
$$X_{(1)}\sim e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2}\Phi(\mu-x)^{n-1}\,,$$
it is feasible to derive a moment estimator or the MLE (which again only depend on $X_{(1)}$ since there is no other observation).

Comment: Can you give some inference result based on my example? (estimating $\mu$)

Comment: @ZHU: the inference result is the MLE based on the distribution of $X_{(1)}$, which is not available in closed form but requires numerical optimisation.